# Lista de checkbox IONIC

Tags: ionic, angulajs

Tengo una mini problema, tengo una lista de `checkbox`pero se descuadra, tengo el siguiente código con la directiva `<ion-checkbox>`

```
   <ion-item class="item-button-right" ng-repeat="item in unitPhysicalStateList" >
        {{item.unitPartName}}
       <div class="buttons">
          <ion-checkbox ng-model="item.good"
             ng-checked="item.good" ng-disabled="item.bad">B</ion-checkbox>
          <ion-checkbox  ng-model="item.bad"
                    ng-checked="item.bad" ng-disabled="item.good">M</ion-checkbox>
       </div>
   </ion-item>
```

CSS:

```
.buttons {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
  min-width: 34px;
  min-height: 34px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 32px; }
```

Pero en el vista se descruada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi lista de checkbox, salen las lineas que son de una lista, alguien sabe como poder quitar la linea o poder mejorar la directiva???.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero estar entendiendo bien tu pregunta.
Las líneas que se muestran es probable que sean los bordes del div, puedes tratar añadiendo un estilo adicional a la clase del botón con:

```
border:none;
```

De ese modo puedes quitar todos los bordes de todos los lados, arriba, abajo, derecha e izquierda así no aparecerán las líneas adicionales que te están molestando.

Solo me causa duda por qué salen en los check de la M y no de la B, pero puedes intentar poner este estilo a ver si cambia como se muestra.

**EDICIÓN**

He creado un pequeño [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tppshaka77/pen/Vdjegp) para ilustrar tu situación. En este caso el borde de las líneas que vez hace parte de la clase "item-checkbox" del Label que se autogenera con el directive ion-checkbox.

En resumen, al usar un ion-checkbox se autogenera un label que puedes ver al "Inspeccionar elemento" en el explorador.

Solución:
Agregar un estilo que sobreescriba el comportamiento de la clase item-checkbox que incluya el estilo de `border:none` De ese modo puedes modificar el estilo de los elementos autogenerados.

Te dejo el link del [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tppshaka77/pen/Vdjegp) para que veas que funciona. El truco esta en el CSS.

Comment: Hola TppShaka77, me ha ayudado tu solución, es correcto lo que mencionas que la lineas la genera la clase del item-checkbox de ionic.css. por eso me causaba ruido, el por que en la letra B, no salía esa linea. pero bueno.

Gracias por la ayuda y saludos!

Comment: Con todo el gusto del mundo Dann. Me alegra que funcionara :)